# Inherit Permissions for new files

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, file-permissions, user-permissions

Is there a way to grant permissions for a directory for specific user such as any created files (suppose auto-created log files) inherit this permissions under Windows via cmd or PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

That already happens. Files created or copied into a folder inherit the security of the folder, unless you or a program changed it.

```
icacls /?
```

for how to see and set security.

```
       C:\Users\User>icacls c:\windows
       c:\windows 
       NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller:(F)
       NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller:(CI)(IO)(F)
       NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(M)
       NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
       BUILTIN\Administrators:(M)
       BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
       BUILTIN\Users:(RX)
       BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)(IO)(GR,GE)
       CREATOR OWNER:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
```

Owner is set to the user except for admins where it is set to admin group.

Comment: Likely this should happen. However I'm installing an app under local admin (elevated permissions are necessary), then grant full permissions for specific user on the app's folder, place the app to autorun (user is set up to log on automatically), reboot. After that the app creates log file and there are no permissions for my specific user.

Comment: And there is one more thing: if I delete this log manually and restart the app (under my non-admin specific user), log is re-created with proper permissions

Comment: @Evgeny: the app might be explicitly setting permissions on the log file.  But double-check the permissions on the folder where the log file is created; in particular check that the permission entry you added for the user has the (IO) flag.